# Dynamic Cell Click on DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an application where it is separated into tabs. Up to 4 tabs can have the same DataGridView on but with different data.

I dynamically create the tabs and the datagrid views and they are named "Entitlements1", "Entitlements2" etc.

I have added a Cell Double Click Event Handler for the DataGridView and it works for both DataGridViews on both tabs, however how can I ascertain which DataGridView it has fired the event for?

My Code:

```
Public Shared Sub EntitlementsDGV(ByVal DriverNo As Integer)

        Dim entdgv As New List(Of DataTable)
        entdgv.Add(New DataTable)
        entdgv.Add(New DataTable)
        entdgv.Add(New DataTable)
        entdgv.Add(New DataTable)
        entdgv.Add(New DataTable)

        'Find Driver Tab Control
        Dim DriverTabCtrl = Functions.FindControl(Results, "DriverTab" & DriverNo)
        'Find GroupBox Control
        Dim GroupBoxCtrl = Functions.FindControl(DriverTabCtrl, "EntitlementGrpBx" & DriverNo)
        'Find DataGridView
        Dim DGVCtrl As DataGridView = Functions.FindControl(GroupBoxCtrl, "Entitlements" & DriverNo)

        entdgv(DriverNo) = Results.EntitlementsTbl.Clone
        Dim result() As DataRow = Results.EntitlementsTbl.Select("Driver = " & DriverNo & "")
        For Each row As DataRow In result
            entdgv(DriverNo).Rows.Add(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5))
        Next

        DGVCtrl.DataSource = entdgv(DriverNo)
        DGVCtrl.Columns(DGVCtrl.Columns.Count - 1).Visible = False

        AddHandler DGVCtrl.CellDoubleClick, AddressOf EntitlementDblClick

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub EntitlementDblClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Entitlement Box Double Click")
    End Sub
```

This is the code for how I dynamically add the DataGridView

```
Dim NewDGV As New DataGridView
            NewDGV.Name = "Entitlements" & DriverNo
            NewDGV.Location = New Point(1, 1)
            DGVSetup(NewDGV)

            NewGrpBx.Controls.Add(NewDGV)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Shared Sub EntitlementDblClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

        MsgBox("Entitlement Box Double Click")

        Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    End Sub
```

dgv will be the datagridview from where the event was fired

Comment: glad it helped, if so do you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: sorry I tried earlier but because you were so quick it gave me the 5 minute warning.